# unable to unset session id in php

Tags: php, html, session

I cannot properly unset the session id of my page unless I close the browser and reopen it. I tried to set the `$_SESSION = null;` and to forcefully set the cookie to a negative value `setcookie('cookiename', '', time()-3600);` but no results yet.

```
<body>

<?php
session_start();
// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = null;
setcookie('cookiename', '', time()-3600);
session_destroy();

print "SESSION has been destroyed - all session data deleted";
?>
```

[back to home page](http://localhost/index.php)

```
</body>
```

Comment: sometimes you just need to clear your cache/cookies from your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is not duplicate!

Comment: i found the issue: instead of setcookie('cookiename', '', time()-3600); the right line of code is: setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-3600);

Comment: Use `session_regenerate_id()` for generating a new session id after destroying the session

Comment: @NineBerry I tried and it did not work. As i just said the fix was session_name()  . Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was session_name() instead of 'cookiename'

Answer (score 0):

replace lab5destroy.php with below code

```
<body>
<?php
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
session_start();
// Unset all of the session variables.
session_regenerate_id();
session_destroy();
print "SESSION has been destroyed - all session data deleted";
?>
<hr>
<a href="http://localhost/lab5.php" rel="nofollow noreferrer">back to home page</a>
</hr>
</body>
```

Comment: if I use $_SESSION = array(); nothing changes

Comment: this is the third time you are changing your answer. I am reporting you for moderator intervention. I already said that the fix was session_name() instead of 'cookiename'

Comment: I tried that before and it was not working. The only fix was session_name() instead of 'cookiename' .

Comment: but i copy ur code in my system and it work fine after changes i made

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```